# Flex Element wrongly keeps properties from previous parent - how do I reset it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to put an element into another component (in this case a print template), print it, and then return it to its place. The problem is that when I return it, it has the properties of the print template! Here is a simplified example. When you click print, the label is removed and then returned but when returned it is affected by the padding of the print template! Why? How can I somehow refresh it to its proper properties? I tried all the invalidate... methods and parentChanged() but nothing worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="200">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.VGroup;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var printTemplate:VGroup = new VGroup();
                printTemplate.paddingTop = 50;
                printTemplate.paddingLeft = 30;

                printTemplate.addElement(label);
                addElement(printTemplate);
                validateNow();

                // print

                removeElement(printTemplate);
                addElement(label);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="Print" right="0" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Label id="label" text="This is the label text, it should appear at the top-left."/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: The label is not removed from the main displayList when you click print, is it normal ? Furthermore, maybe you should try to call again validate() ?

Comment: I tried validateNow() and it didn't do anything.

Comment: When you say it has the properties of the print template, do you mean the styles? Layout?

Comment: If you run the code you'll see that "label" gets the padding of the "printTemplate" element. Also, let's say you put a button at the top of printTemplate, when "label" is returned to the its original spot it will be pushed down by the size of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I hacked up a solution. Put this in before adding the label back to its proper place:

```
var vg:VGroup = new VGroup();
vg.addElement(label);
addElement(vg);
validateNow();
removeElement(vg);
```

Then it gets the padding from "vg", which has no padding set. Yay. Another little hack to circumnavigate a Flex bug.

Comment: I think if you run the example code you'll see. It's hard to explain further in words than it is explained in the question.

Comment: I raised it as a question, because a bug is usually something that was specified how it should work, but ends up behaving differently. I would agree that this is a Flex bug, when I see what has been stated on Flex side as "should do X, Y, Z" and what are the actual deviations from this stated behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a separate **print view**-component which has a separate label which you only need to pass the right data.

Comment: Yes I looked into that but this is a simplified example, in reality what I want to print is a VGroup containing a number of complex elements, to rebuild all these elements requires a lot of horrible code. What I'm trying to do is not unreasonable, or rather what Flex is doing to me is unreasonable :-). There must be a solution to do it the way I want...

Comment: I assume the horrible code is already written and it is used in the actual view. So what stands in your way of reusing it? Changing the parent item just for printing purposes sounds like adding more horrible stuff to the already horrible stuff. How is that reasonable?

Comment: There is currently no horrible code. To recreate the elements which are in the view and apply the changes that the user has made to them would require code though.

Comment: A common technique is to make your components and views data-driven, meaning that controlling these is just a matter of setting the component or views data. Usually such data is called a Model... So basically all you need is to create the DisplayView and PrintView in a way that they only need a reference to the same model - the view would be updated with data binding. The printing would be a matter of instantiating the PrintView, setting the model, wait for creation completion, adding it to the print job and print it.

Comment: Yeah there is some of that in there but there are also parts of the components that don't make sense to have in a model because they are not shared or of interest to any other objects. The essence of object-oriented programming is that an object has properties and state etc. So that would then have to be replicated to the new print version. I could put all that state into the model but that would be major code bloat.

Comment: So where do you propose to put it? Essentially you're dealing with Model (the pure data) + Presentation Model (data transformed into presentation data, can also hold the visual state of a component). We're talking about something very specific, so leave aside the essence of OOP to Alan Kay. If taking an existing instance from somewhere and placing it elsewhere is the only means of reusing it in your architecture... - that thing alone talks a lot about how you understand OOP.